# Why doesn't FoxPro release my APP file?

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm porting an old FoxPro app to Visual FoxPro.  The old program of course did not use any classes, but I've started to use them for certain cases.  This has caused a problem in the development cycle that I don't see mentioned anywhere.

Basically, if I create an object based on a class defined in a procedure file, then FoxPro will never let go of my APP.  I can't delete it or rebuild it, and I have to restart VFP every time I make a change.

Steps to reproduce.  Make `a.prg` with

```
SET PROCEDURE TO b
m.test1 = CREATEOBJECT('TestClass')
RELEASE m.test1
```

and make `b.prg` with

```
DEFINE CLASS TestClass AS Control
ENDDEFINE
```

Create a project called `a`:

```
MODIFY PROJECT a
```

And add the program `a.prg`.  Then

```
BUILD APP a FROM a
DO a.app
DELETE FILE a.app
```

The last line will give

```
Application file 'c:\...\b.fxp' is not closed
```

Then if you try the `DELETE` again, it will say

```
File access is denied c:\...\a.app
```

I can see in Process Explorer that `vfp9.exe` has a handle on the APP file that never goes away until I quit FoxPro, no matter what I try:

- SET PROCEDURE TO
- CLOSE ALL
- RELEASE ALL
- CANCEL
- CLEAR ALL
- ad nauseum

Comment: I am using VFP 7 and you can't issue a `build app a from a` command becuase it will throw a `file a.pjx does not exist` error. Do you have a a.pjx file? Perhaps version 9.0 is different?

Comment: @DaveB, thanks for trying this.  I forgot to mention that I created a project "a.pjx" and added a.prg.  You have to do that interactively (i.e. it can't be scripted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
CLEAR CLASS TestClass
```

(which incidentally is not indexed in the help file).

In the real app, I've had to carefully script the release procedures so that I can recover from this state in the event of an error.  But `CLEAR CLASS` was the missing link.

Comment: This is what worked for me, although [Pavel Celba reported on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/visualfoxprogeneral/thread/723bb6e1-e48a-42c0-9507-351c0b3faeda) the same as @DRapp here, that `SET PROCEDURE TO` was sufficient.  I don't know how to account for the different experience, but I hope this question is clear enough to help others one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [CANCEL Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf6xebad%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> Ends execution of the current Visual FoxPro program file. Control
>   returns to the Command window when Visual FoxPro is being used
>   interactively. If a distributed run-time application is running,
>   CANCEL terminates the application and control returns to Windows. If a
>   program is executing in Visual FoxPro during design time, CANCEL
>   terminates the program and control returns to the Command window.
>   Executing CANCEL releases all private variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I should have listed CANCEL among the things I tried.  But this situation remains after the program has finished executing, so there is nothing to cancel at that point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see CLEAR ALL among the things you tried. My standard clean-up is:

```
CLOSE ALL
CLEAR ALL
```

Tamar

Answer (score 0):

I did what you had almost verbatim... only change was in a.prg

```
SET PROCEDURE TO b
m.test1 = CREATEOBJECT('TestClass')
RELEASE m.test1
SET PROCEDURE TO   <-- I Added this line
```

In addition, your attempt to
DELETE A.App   WOULD have failed... Unless it was an oops.

DELETE is a command to delete records from a table.  I THINK you meant
ERASE a.App
Because no table was available, it couldn't act on the DELETE command and may have been giving you a misdirected message.   But by putting the closing "SET PROCEDURE TO" at the end of the "a.prg"  allowed it to properly close and erase the a.app file when finished.

Comment: thanks very much for trying this.  You're right, I meant `DELETE FILE`, although `BUILD APP` yielded the same message.  Please see my answer for other findings.